Shadow DOM automation
I am trying to automated using puppeteer. How can I select option from shadow dom. Screenshot showing shadow dom inside this there is select option. I am trying to select option using puppeteer.
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");


(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    defaultViewport: null,
    args: ["--start-maximized"],
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  //page.setDefaultTimeout(0);
  await page.goto("https://mixam.co.uk/");
  await page.waitForNetworkIdle();


  let shadow = await page.evaluateHandle(() => {
    let elem = document.querySelector(
      "body > div.bg-pastel-lavender > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.h-min-650.h-100 > div > price-calculator"
    ).shadowRoot;
    return elem;
  });

  console.log(shadow);

  await shadow.select("#Size", "4-NONE");

  await browser.close();
})();


I'd remove that spurious await page.waitForNetworkIdle();, likely a race condition. Avoid that predicate in most cases, but if you do need to use it, add it to the goto: page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "networkidle2"}). Puppeteer offers >>> to penetrate the shadow DOM, so await shadow.select(">>> #Size", "4-NONE"); should work, but doing it by hand should work too. What's the specific problem with this code and what's your high-level goal here?

Thank you for your reply, I found solution for this.

Great. Please post a self answer to help other people with the same problem.

To interact with shadow dom with puppeteer. Keep everything same like normal dom except selectors.To Handle element from shadow dom add ">>>" before selector.
For example
await page.click("selector")//for regular dom
await page.click(">>>selector")//for shadow dom

